# How to inject into environment variables the user-name and password of the user that triggered the build

Tags: jenkins, ldap, credentials

I'm trying to configure Jenkins so if some user run a job, it will be ran under its same account on the corresponding node.
I'm currently using LDAP to manage users in jenkins, and the same LDAP is configured in the nodes.
So for me it would be as simple as injecting into the environment variables the user_name and password of who triggered the job. And then do some "su" or "sudo" before running the actual script.

Is there any way to make this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Getting the username would be fairly easy given that the username is the same one that used to login to Jenkins. Getting the password, however, will be much more difficult (if at all possible) since that would have to be extracted from AD.